# Why does bpf_redirect silently discards packages when the target is a VTI interface?

Tags: c, linux, networking, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I am using XDP to process network packages. I want to redirect packages to a dedicated network interface using `bpf_redirect(target_interface, 0)`. This works fine, unless the target interface is a VTI interface (part of an IPsec tunnel established by strongswan). In this case, no package is transmitted over the tunnel.

I assumed the package was dropped by the kernel for some reason and used [dropwatch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dropwatch) to check for discarded network traffic - but there was not a single discarded package.

If I just changed the target IP from XDP, return `XDP_PASS` and let the Linux routing do its work, the package processing works fine. Unfortunately I am required to forcefully select the the interface here.

Do you have any idea why this happens and the redirection is not working?

I ensured `bpf_redirect` was returning `XDP_REDIRECT` and ensured the same code was working with different kinds of network interface (physical NICs and VXLAN interfaces).

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example for this? How did you check whether a packet was transmitted over the IPsec tunnel?